# java.io.IOException when running grails project

Tags: grails, ubuntu-12.04, grails-2.0

I got a grails Project from my friend, i imported that project in GGTS and after i refreshed dependence, i have no error.

When i trying to run I got

**Error Error executing script RunApp: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "grails": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)**

I am using Ubuntu 12.4.

But, i imported same project in my another system which runs in windows 7, i didn't get any error or exception in windows.

What is the reason for this Exception ?

### **echo $PATH**  output

/home/ard006/Documents/senchaCmd/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250:/home/ard006/Viswa/scala/sbt/bin:/home/ard006/Documents/senchaCmd/Sencha/Cmd/3.0.0.250:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/ard006/Viswa/springsource/grails-2.1.2/bin:/home/ard006/groovy-2.0.0/bin

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? I am getting the same issue.


Here is the PATH


/home/sashwat/.gvm/vertx/current/bin:/home/sashwat/.gvm/springboot/current/bin:/home/sashwat/.gvm/lazybones/current/bin:/home/sashwat/.gvm/groovyserv/current/bin:/home/sashwat/.gvm/groovy/current/bin:/home/sashwat/.gvm/griffon/current/bin:/home/sashwat/.gvm/grails/current/bin:/home/sashwat/.gvm/gradle/current/bin:/home/sashwat/.gvm/glide/current/bin:/home/sashwat/.gvm/gaiden/current/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like GGTS can't find the grails executable.

Is it on your `PATH` ? I suspect you need to set the `PATH` variable thus:

```
$ PATH=$GRAILSHOME/bin:$PATH
```

and then invoke GGTS from that shell, such that it inherits the `PATH` setting (I've assumed `PATH` is exported)

Comment: I have following lines in .bashrc file ,
export GRAILS_HOME=/home/ard006/Viswa/springsource/grails-2.1.2

export PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin,

Answer (score 0):

Just run into the same problem.

I had the Grails bin folder on the path using this notation in the .bash.rc file

```
export PATH="${PATH}:~/grails/bin"
```

The tilde broke it and I changed it to:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/home/myuser/grails/bin"
```

Now it's working, the IOException is gone.